# Monitor AWS instance using cloudwatch on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js

I'm trying to build an app that monitors AWS instances by a given instance IP.
Now, I managed to get a response from the instance but this is - the Datapoints returns empty.
Constrains:

- the Dimensions are unknown to me
- the Namespace is unknown as well I used EC2 as an arbitrary value
  The code reaching to AWS servers:

```
    const winston = require('winston');
    const { CloudWatchClient, GetMetricStatisticsCommand, ListMetricsCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-cloudwatch");
    const config = require('config');
    
    const region = config.get('region');
    
    const cwClient = new CloudWatchClient({ region: region });
    
    const getCPUUtilization = async (ip, timePeriod, interval) => {
        let today = new Date();
        let dateToStart = new Date();
        let dateOffset = (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) * timePeriod;
        dateToStart.setTime(today.getTime() - dateOffset);
        const params = {
    
            Dimensions: [
                {
                    Name: "InstanceId",
                    Value: "i-test",
                }
            ],
            Namespace: `AWS/EC2`,
            MetricName: 'CPUUtilization',
            Period: interval,
            Unit: "Percent",
            StartTime: dateToStart,
            EndTime: today,
            Statistics: ["Maximum", "Minimum", "Average"],
        };
        try {
            return await cwClient.send(new GetMetricStatisticsCommand(params));
    
        } catch (err) {
    
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
    module.exports = getCPUUtilization;
```

The output I'm getting:

```
    {
      '$metadata': {
        httpStatusCode: 200,
        requestId: '192bce9c-42b0-4820-9b66-ca0c8a4e0159',
        extendedRequestId: undefined,
        cfId: undefined,
        attempts: 1,
        totalRetryDelay: 0
      },
      Label: 'CPUUtilization',
      Datapoints: []
    }
```

I would really appreciate your help,
thank you in advance